# Disable listview click or touch while scrolling items android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

How to disable listview touch or click while scrolling listitems. 
I am doing listview scroll on button click event and i need listview
   click disable while scrolling.
I want to make listview to wheel-view

Answer (score 1):

Use `setOnScrollListener`

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                isScrolling = false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
           isScrolling = true;
        }
    });
```

and in the `setOnItemClickListener` do that:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        if(!isScrolling){
            //do your code
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set OnScrollListener on the listview as below

```
setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() { 
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
} 

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        Log.i("a", "scrolling stopped...");
         //attach the click listerner here
    } else if(scrollState==OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
         //remove the click listener here

    } 
});
```